# cron and bundle exec problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cron, bundler

I've upgraded to rails 3.0.9 which has introduced the rake issues. I've gotten it all resolved except for a problem with a cron job.

This used to work:

```
#!/bin/sh
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm 
cd /home/p1r65759/apps/abbc/
/usr/local/bin/rake refresh_events RAILS_ENV=production
```

But now I get this error:
You have already activated rake 0.8.7, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2. Consider using bundle exec.
/home/p1r65759/apps/abbc/Rakefile:4:in `'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

How do I modify my script to use bundle exec so it will use the proper version of rake and run successfully?
Thanks.

Comment: Having a similar issue, but sans RVM.  Anyway, maybe you can specify the path to rake 0.9.2 or update your system rake gem to 0.9.2 (depending on if this is the only app on the server...)

Comment: Fixed, thanks to tech support at HostingRails.com. Just changed the last line to bundle exec rake refresh_events RAILS_ENV=production. Didn't need the path in front of it either. I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: Add that as an answer, then, and accept it.  For posterity and future googlers :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using bundler for your application then you don't need to use "/usr/local/bin/rake" as a path for rake.

you can just use

```
bundle exec rake
```

so your new script will be

```
#!/bin/sh
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm 
cd /home/p1r65759/apps/abbc/
bundle exec rake refresh_events RAILS_ENV=production
```

bundle exec will work because you are already in your project directory.

And don't forgot to include rake in your Gemfile.

Answer (score 4):

instead of

```
/usr/local/bin/rake refresh_events RAILS_ENV=production
```

you should use

```
bundle exec rake refresh_events RAILS_ENV=production
```

or better yet install your bundle with --binstubs:

```
bundle install --binstubs --without development test
```

then you will have bin/rake:

```
./bin/rake refresh_events RAILS_ENV=production
```